# Can SkiaSharp be used in a WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, skiasharp

I know a `SkiaSharp` canvas can be placed in a `Grid` in a Xamarin App.  Here is some example (working) code:

```
xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
```

```
<skia:SKCanvasView 
    x:Name="AUView"
    Grid.Row="2"
    PaintSurface="AUView_PaintSurface" />
```

But when I try to do a similar thing in a WPF App:

```
xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp;assembly=SkiaSharp"
```

```
<skia:SKCanvas
   Name="AUView"
   Grid.Row="2"
   PaintSurface="AUView_PaintSurface" />
```

I get the error:

```
A value of type 'SKCanvas' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.
```

Is it possible to put an `SKCanvas` in a grid cell in WPF or does the whole of the page have to be an `SKCanvas`?

Else, how/can you use `SkiaSharp` in WPF?

Comment: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/master/samples/Basic/WPF

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you have to install the [`SkiaSharp.Views.WPF`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views.WPF/2.80.1) package, which will automatically install [`SkiaSharp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp/), too. The `SkiaSharp` package alone will not contain the needed WPF control, which is [`SKElement`](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/2e83c18263d87262fedd5c859dea535d1d2c46a8/source/SkiaSharp.Views/SkiaSharp.Views.WPF/SKElement.cs#L16).

As it is a `FrameworkElement`, you can place it anywhere in your view. `SKCanvas` is not a WPF compatible component. To use an `SKElement` in your XAML, you have to pull in its XML namespace.

```
xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.WPF;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.WPF"
```

Then place the `SKCanvas` control anywhere in your view.

```
<skia:SKElement
      Name="AUView"
      Grid.Row="2"
      PaintSurface="AUView_PaintSurface"/>
```

Comment: Believe it or not, I did not see the ...WPF Nuget package.  Now installed and with the help of the examples pointed out earlier, it is all working.  Thanks.